# Caused by: XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring application that doest user registration and allows a user to enter data using CRUD in spring mvc. When I launch the application I get this error as a stackrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 110; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

this is the second line of stacktrace that the error throws

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 110; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    atm.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

this is the class that defined in my web-inf folder where the error is located

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Assuming that everything is fine, please why am I getting the above error when I launch my application. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

you miss the xml xsd like below

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
"
```

Comment: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare all the XML namespaces before using them in your document, including the `xsi` one.

Here's the complete beans declaration for your use case:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
">
```